# Laravel - subdomain routing not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have three routing files inside routes folder:

- web.php
- api.php
- admin.php

I've registered the file `admin.php` inside `boot()` method of `RouteServiceProvider` as following:

```
public function boot() {
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::domain("admin." . env("APP_URL"))
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path("routes/admin.php"));

        Route::domain("api." . env("APP_URL"))
            ->middleware("api")
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path("routes/api.php"));

        Route::middleware("web")
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path("routes/web.php"));
    });
}
```

Let's say i've defined the following route in web.php:

```
Route::get("test", function() {
    return "Hello from website route";
});
```

If i try to access this route using **mywebsite.com/test** it acts like expected.

However, if i try to access the link **admin.mywebsite.com/test** it would still some how falls back to **mywebsite.com/test** and give the exact same output.

What's the problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `web.php` is not restricted to a domain. As a consequence, the routes defined there are accessed by every domain that targets your laravel application.

If you only want the root domain to access the routes defined in your `web.php`, you could specify it in the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
Route::middleware("web")
   ->domain(env("APP_URL")) // Add this line
   ->namespace($this->namespace)
   ->group(base_path("routes/web.php"));
```

Comment: How did I not think of that before?, it was in front of me all the time.
Nevertheless, this answer worked fine for me, and mostly important everything seems logical, nothing odd ...